# Comprehending $\sum_{\ell = 0}^{2L+1} \sum_{j+k = \ell} x_{j,k}$

Tags: summation, notation

I'm having trouble comprehending the following notation (for a double sequence of complex numbers $(x_{m,n})_{m,n = 0}^{\infty}$):

$$ \sum_{\ell = 0}^{2L+1} \sum_{j+k = \ell} x_{j,k} \ ;$$

in particular, what does $\sum_{j+k = \ell} x_{j,k}$ look like? This is in relation to the following array<sup>[(src)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GN71u.png)</sup>

$$ \begin{array}{rrrrr}
-1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots \\
\frac{1}{2} & -1 & 0 & 0 & \cdots \\
\frac{1}{4} & \frac{1}{2} & -1 & 0 & \cdots \\
\frac{1}{8} & \frac{1}{4} & \frac{1}{2} & -1 & \cdots \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots
\end{array} $$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- $\sum_{j+k = \ell} x_{j,k}=\sum_{j=0}^\ell x_{j,\ell-j}.$

For instance
$\sum_{j+k=2} x_{j,k}=x_{0,2}+x_{1,1}+x_{2,0}=\frac14+(-1)+0.$

- $\sum_{\ell = 0}^n \sum_{j+k = \ell} x_{j,k}=
  \sum_{j+k\le n
  } x_{j,k}.$

For instance
$\sum_{\ell = 0}^1\sum_{j+k = \ell} x_{j,k}=
x_{0,0}+x_{0,1}+x_{1,0}=-1+\frac12+0.$